# Как передать параметры скриптом?

Tags: javascript

Допустим имеется ссылка `<a href="site.ru" class="js-goto-link">link</a>`
И есть скрипт:

```
activate();

function activate() {
    $(document).on("click", ".js-goto-link", gotoLinkHandler);
}

function gotoLinkHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var referer = localStorage.getItem('referal');
    window.location.href = href + (referer ? "?referer=" + referer : "");
}
```

В будущем могут быть ещё добавлены новые атрибуты сервисов, которые нужно также передавать в get-параметрах ссылки.
Как можно добавлять новые параметры к referer, т.е. те, которые за ранее не известны ?

Comment: а к чему они будут добавлены? к ссылке как параметры?

Comment: @Oleksandr, да, к ссылке. Возможно это будут какие-то онлайн-сервисы с параметрами

Comment: дайте пример как это должно выглядеть. `<a param1='dsawd' param2='dawdwadaw' href="site.ru" class="js-goto-link">link</a>` или как?

Comment: @Oleksandr, дело в том, за ранее не известно, в каком виде будут параметры. Т.е. сначала вместо тега `a` была кнопка `button` с data-href. Меня попросили переделать кнопку в ссылку `<a>`, про параметры не известно. При этом сказали будут вешать какие-то параметры на ссылку

Comment: @word а в каком хотя бы виде придут параметры? как мы вообще узнаем за что зацепиться, где взять данные? хотя бы где они будут находиться

Comment: @lazyproger, будут находиться в атрибутах ссылки

Comment: @word уточняю. те у тебя будут какие то атрибуты, и тебе нужно будет их подставить в ссылку?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nap2pvry/